# Items does not get inserted at end of SQL table android

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending data from my android app to be added to the online database. But the data does not gets stored at end of table. It gets stored at random position in table. How do I avoid this? here is my php code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$response = array();

$title = $_POST['Title'];
$time = $_POST['Time'];
$posted= $_POST['posted'];




require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


$db = new DB_CONNECT();


$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mukul(Title, Time, posted) VALUES('$title', '$time', '$posted')");

if ($result) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";


    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";


    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Comment: it's not sqlite database, it's php and mysql, so I suggest you edit your post so that people with experience in those things can answer you

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but is important anyway. Do not use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated, and the way you use them makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Instead, use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an "end of a table" in relational databases. The data is stored in whatever order is most convenient for the database (which is affected by the indexes on the table). So what you're asking about is not a bug at all but expected behavior. Just use the `ORDER BY` clause when fetching the data to ensure the order you want. Contrary to what you may believe (I have to guess since question is a bit vague), doing an `ORDER BY` is not a slow operation, especially if you have an index on the sorted column(s).

If you need help with indexes, [the MySQL manual has you covered](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html).